# iptables does not start after reboot

Tags: boot, server, iptables, reboot

I have already run the command, `systemctl enable iptables` and `systemctl start iptables`, but the iptables service was not started as message below after I reboot server.

```
root@sec-k8-m1-iwt:~# systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service - netfilter persistent configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/alternatives/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:netfilter-persistent(8)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You check via `sudo iptables -xvnL`. The loading service is as expected, I think, I don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on the `systemctl` status of `iptables` to determine if it's up.  The service simply is a onetime service called at boot to run `iptables-restore` from `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `/etc/iptables/rules.v6`.  It's not a persistent services.

You would check via `sudo iptables -xvnL` or similar commands to make sure that `iptables` rules have populated.

Comment: Thomas, thank a lot. I found that the rules have already loaded by using iptables -xvnL. The rules are effective after test.